# Why does a pointer to a multidimensional array return segmentation fault when accessed after passing the pointer to a function?

Tags: c, arrays

So I don't really know what this problem is really called so searching and googling leads to different answers which does not answer my question.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gen_matrix(int **array, int rm, int cm) {
    // int ** array;
    int r, c;

    array = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * rm);

    for (int r = 0; r < rm; ++r) {
        array[r] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * cm);

        for (int c = 0; c < cm; ++c) {
            array[r][c] = 1;
        } // c
    } // r
}// gen_matrix

int main() {
    int **a;
    gen_matrix(a, 2, 2);

    printf("%d", a[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `printf()` in `main()` returns `Segmentation Fault`. What I found out is that the address that the pointer `a` in `main()` points to does not change when `malloc()` is used inside `gen_matrix()`.
In `gen_matrix()`, I can access the array just fine, but after I return to `main()`, the pointer `a` does not point to the array `malloc()` created.

Thank you.

Comment: you are missing one more level of indirection. Either do a `int *** array` parameter to a function, or an `int ** & array`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, where do I put int *** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the update to `array` when `gen_matrix()` returns, because you are not passing it the address of `a`.  You could add an extra indirection level by passing in the address of `a` to `gen_matrix()`, but it would be cleaner to just have `gen_matrix()` return the malloced address and assign it to `a` in `main()`:

```
int **gen_matrix(int rm, int cm) {
    int ** array;

    array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * rm);

    for (int r = 0; r < rm; ++r) {
        array[r] = malloc(sizeof(*(array[r])) * cm);

        for (int c = 0; c < cm; ++c) {
            array[r][c] = 1;
        } // c
    } // r

    return array;
}// gen_matrix

int main() {
    int **a;
    a = gen_matrix(2, 2);

    printf("%d", a[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, it's not a good idea to cast the return from `malloc()` and it is preferable to dereference the pointer the memory is being assigned to to get the proper size for `sizeof()`.

And you should of course `free()` the memory before exiting.

Comment: Good call, being a 3-star programmer is rarely a compliment in C.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function the parameter `int ** array` is the "array itself". What you need is a reference to it, either with one more level of pointer indirection or a C++-style reference. So, what you do is you modify the function to accept a triple-pointer:

```
void gen_matrix(int ** * array, int rm, int cm) {
```

and when you call it you also get the address of the "pointer to the matrix":

```
gen_matrix(&a, 2, 2);
```

of course you have to modify the code in the function to take care of that extra indirection:

```
*array = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * rm);
```

and in the other two places as well.

Comment: `int **array` passes a copy of the pointer `a` as `array` to the function, not the "array itself". The copy holds the same address as it *value* as the original did, but the pointer itself has its very own, and very different address. That is why the address assigned to `array` within the function is not seen back in the caller. Passing `&a` passes the `address of the pointer itself -- so changes made to the pointer are seen back in the caller. I understand this is what you were thinking, but it technically isn't what you wrote... (better to return a pointer, than be a 3-star programmer)

Comment: "3-star programmer" made me smile. Cute and witty remark, I like it :) As for the rest - I'm not sure what are you saying is wrong with my code. Yes, a triple-pointer use is not the best idea here (I was trying to keep the function return as-is and only modify the passed-in parameter) but the ugliness of that solution doesn't make it invalid (technically).